# Neo4j Cypher query execution and fetch result in java is very slow

Tags: neo4j

I am using Neo4j in java as stand alone application.
I am facing problem in fetch result from ExecutionResult, which is very slow.

```
        long start1= System.currentTimeMillis();
        er= (ExecutionResult)graphDb.execute(query);    
        long end1= System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("ExecutionResult time:"+ (end1-start1));

        long start= System.currentTimeMillis();

        Iterator<Node> personResultIterator = er.columnAs("columnname");
        while(personResultIterator.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(personResultIterator.next());
               }

        long end= System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Iterator time : "+ (end-start));
```

ExecutionResult time:21

Iterator time : 2493

Iterator is taking too must time. I also tries DumpString, ResultasString and JsonHelper to fetch values from execution Result they are also take same amount of time.
Executing query is not taking time but fetching values from execution result is very slow.
Please help in resolving this.

Regards

Comment: You may want to leave out `System.out.println()` from the loop and just do `personResultIterator.next()` and check execution time. Sometimes that can slow down your timing by quite a bit.

Comment: thanks for you reply, issue was with cypher query. We were using regex operator for ignoring case sensitivity which is taking time. we change our nodes to lower case and search string in lower case.